# Regex for extracting string between patterns

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Need some help with the regex to be used for extracting string between a start_pattern and an end_pattern. Additionally, the regex should grep all characters upto the end of line if no end_pattern exists.

```
Sample 1 : "BOOK1:book1A,book1B,book1C,book1D"
```

Expected Result : book1A,book1B,book1C,book1D

```
Sample 2 : "BOOK1:book1A,book1B,book1C,book1D|BOOK2:book2A,book2B,book2C,book2DA"
```

Expected Result : (1)book1A,book1B,book1C,book1D
(2)book2A,book2B,book2C,book2DA

I've managed to resolve the regex (shown below) when the string terminator is "|", but cannot get around to resolving it when there is no terminator

```
(?<=BOOK1:).*(?=\|)
```

Comment: You may want to add a question mark at the end: `(?<=BOOK1:).*?(?=\|)?`, also you should use the non-greedy `.*?` instead of the greedy `.*` unless you want "Sample 2" to match `book1A,book1B,book1C,book1D|BOOK2:book2A,book2B,book2C,book2DA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` and change `.*` to `.*?`

```
(?<=BOOK1:|\|).*?(?=\||$)
```

`$` marks the end of line or string

`.*?` would match lazily

---

For example, for input

```
a|b|c|d|e
```

with regex

```
(?<=\|).*(?=\|)
```

it would match `b|c|d`

with regex

```
(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)
```

it would match

```
b
c
d
```